# ConcurrentMap entries synchronization without blocking whole map

Tags: java, multithreading

Rest service have many customers which are not related to each other.
Each customer can start voting process any time. 
Once customer adds first vote I create an entry in

```
ConcurrentMap<customerId, ConcurrentMap<voteId, voteTimestamp>> votesByCustomer;
```

Each vote have voteTimestamp, so when it expires - it is being removed from the map by another thread. (This removal is not a simple `votesByCustomer.remove()` call, it involves several subsequent calls to the `votesByCustomer` map, hence have to be synchronized additionally).
So, the above `votesByCustomer` map is shared between all customers. (Implemented as a field in enum-backed singleton).

There are many operations with this map which involves several calls to `votesByCustomer` to be done in the atomic way. So I use  `syncronized(votesByCustomer) {}` expression.

So when these methods are called it locks all customers.

My question is how do I write code in such a way so when I'm doing operations for one customer it doesn't look other ones.

I feel like I'm trying to solve an already solved problem, and there is a perfect API and good approach for this, but I can't really make a proper google request. Can you give some tips, please? I use Java8 and Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to safely and quickly get the specific `ConcurrentMap` associated with that customer (or create a new one if none exists), then use a `synchronized` block on that customer-specific `ConcurrentMap` for all the operations that are specific to that customer.

The major danger I can see is that if your vote expiration process ever removes a customer entry from `votesByCustomer` then you could end up in a race condition where you record a vote to a ConcurrentHashMap that's no longer associated with that customer. So you'd have to make sure you leave an empty `ConcurrentMap` in there even for customers whose votes have all expired.